# Kafka org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter doesn't work as values for key.converter and value.converter

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to build a pipeline where I have to move binary data from kafka topic to kinesis stream with out transforming. So I'm planning to use **ByteArrayConverter** for worker properties setup. But I'm getting the following error! Although I could see the ByteArrayConverter class in [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/0.11.0/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/converters/ByteArrayConverter.java#L17)

on 0.11.0 version. I cannot find the same class under 3.2.x :(

Any help would be much appreciated.

`key.converter=io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter for configuration key.converter: Class io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:672)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:418)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.<init>(WorkerConfig.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig.<init>(DistributedConfig.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:65)
```

Comment: Just to make it clear. I'm using confluent-kafka 3.0.1 version.

Comment: Confluent Kafka 3.0.1 doesn't include this converter. You need to use a version that includes it or download and jar it up yourself. Apache Kafka is probably what you want. Confluent Enterprise also includes this converter on 3.2. The open source version will not include this until 3.3.

Answer (score 4):

org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter was only added to Apache Kafka 0.11 (which is Confluent 3.3). If you are running a Confluent distro earlier than 3.3 then you will need the Confluent Enterprise distro (not Confluent Open Source) and use the io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter converter

Comment: Also could you please let me know the difference between `org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter‌` and `io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverte‌​r`? Does both serve the same purpose?

Comment: They both do the same thing. It's just that the Replicator one is not open source and only ships with Confluent Enterprise, while the Apache Kafka one is now open source and ships with all versions of Kafka from 0.11 or higher.